# Provide equality for NUnits results

Tags: c#, nunit, equality

We have the `Result`-argument for all kinds of parameterized tests on NUnit. This works well for simple types where equality is built into .NET. However I wonder if there´s a way to verify a test-method returns a complex object:

```
[TestCase("MyValue", Result = new MyType(...) /* doesn't work as we can only use compile-time constants for attributes */]
public MyType Check(string value)
{
    var target = ...
    return target.DoSomething(value);
}
```

Assuming `target.DoSomething` returns an instance of `MyType` the test should ensure that the returned instance is equal to what I provided within my `TestCase`. As `MyType` does neither implement `IEquatable` nor override `Equals` equality is determined using `ReferenceEquals` which of course is wrong. Moreover as mentioned in my comment we can't create an instance of `MyType` within the attribute as it's no compile-time constant.

So how can we provide a complex instance to our test and check if the outcome is equal to that one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the `TestCaseSource`-attribute for this which allows to determine a member that provides more sophisticated use for testcases. Thus we can also return complex instances of any type. However as allready mentioned we can´t rely on the `Result`-tag of our `TestCase` as it implicitely compare the provided instance with te returned one using the default comparerer which uses `ReferencEEquals`.

So we don´t provide the expected outcome as `Result` but as simple argument to the test and provide our own logic for what is condidered equal:

```
[TestCaseSource("TestcaseMethod")] 
public MyType Check(string value, MyType expected)
{
    var target = ...
    var actual = target.DoSomething(value);
    bool retVal = // check the properties of actual towards those of expected
    Assert.IsTrue(retVal);
}
public IEnumerable<object> TestcaseMethod()
{
    yield return new object[] { "MyValue", new MyType(/* expected outcome */);
    yield return new object[] { "AnotherValue", new MyType(/* expected outcome */);
}
```

where

```
public class MyType
{
    // here come the actual values to be compared
}
```

EDIT: A more straightforward way to check for equality in an `Assert`-statement is to use an [`EqualConstraint`](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/EqualConstraint):

```
Assert.That(expected, Is.EqualTo(actual).Using(new MyComparer());
```

which will use a custom comparer.

Comment: For example FluentAssertions library have assertion extension method `actual.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(expected)` which will compare complex types by their values - will be nice addition to your answer

Answer (score 0):

We use to use Fody Equals to compare custom classes [Equals](https://github.com/Fody/Equals), there is a nuget packet to install it. In order to use it just to put Equals as header decorator and you should able to compare it properly

Comment: That would expect the attribute to be present on `MyType` for the sake of testing it which I´d like to avoid. I´d rather apply that logic within the actual test.

Answer (score 0):

The ExpectedResult attribute is just a bit of syntactic niceness and isn't required in any way. You can always just add an extra argument to the method, giving the expected value, and test it in any way you like within your test.

We have no plan to enhance the internal equality comparison that is used by NUnit to check your ExpectedResult.

Comment: That´s what I allready wrote within my own answer, but thanks for pointing out that there won´t be any support for this.

Comment: Actually your answer (you answered yourself, I guess) wasn't there for me when I posted mine. Looking at it now, however, it states that NUnit uses ReferenceEquals for expected results. That's not correct. It uses exactly the same comparison as an EqualConstraint you would write yourself.

Comment: In your case, it would have used ReferenceEquals whether through an expected result or through a direct assertion in your code. In other cases, for other users who have overridden equality in some way, it won't.

Comment: So it boils down to equality - be it by using the `Result`-attribute an `EqualsConstraint` within an `Assert`-statement - is checked by either `IEquatable` or `object.Equals` or - if none of those is implemented - just `ReferenceEquals` (if I remember right this is also the right order in which the checks are executed).

Comment: @HimBromBeere Simplified, but yes. For example, array equality is defined in NUnit as having all the members equal, in the same order, etc. NUnit has a personal take on equality, which is intended to work with the needs of assertions of equality. When you use an assertion, there is a hook to say that you want to use a particular comparer. That's not possible when using the ExpectedResult property of TestCase.